# How to find current positions of cursors in a textbox or listbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to find current positions of cursors in any textbox or listbox?

Comment: r u want x y cordinate value or charindex in textbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it's WinForms you probably want `TextBox.SelectionStart` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx).